# Understanding edges and vertices in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

This question comes from the most recent math subject GRE posted on their website (problem 13). It deals with graph theory, which I know virtually none of, so I skipped it. However, reading the question again afterwards, I will say that the potential answers to choose from make absolutely no sense to me.

Here's the question: Let G be a graph such that every two distinct vertices in G are connected by exactly one edge and every edge connects two distinct vertices. If G has 190 edges, how many vertices does G have?

The correct answer is 20.

This doesn't seem possible to me. If each edge connects two distinct vertices, shouldn't G have more vertices than it does edges?

Comment: No. Each of the $n$ vertices is connected with the other $n-1$ vertices, that is each vertex has $n-1$ edges connected to it. That explains why there are so many more edges than vertices. In fact the number of edges is given by $\frac{n(-1)}2$. Solving for $n$ given that $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=190$ gives $n=20$

Comment: Are you reading "each edge connects two distinct vertices" as "no two edges share an endpoint"? If so, that would suggest more vertices than edges - but would also contradict the other claims in the problem. I interpret "each edge connects two distinct vertices" as "there is no edge between a vertex and itself". It is admittedly not the best wording.